# How to add Input Field Inside Data table

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using the following method to show multiple `mat-cell` using `*ngFor`:

```
columns = [
    { columnDef: 'qty', header: 'Qty', cell: (row: SaleItem) => `${row.quantity}` },
    { columnDef: 'discount', header: 'Discount', cell: (row: SaleItem) => `${row.discount}` }
  ];

  salesItemsDisplayedColumns = this.columns.map(x => x.columnDef);
```

html file :

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="salesItemsDataSource">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                {{column.cell(row)}}
              </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="salesItemsDisplayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:salesItemsDisplayedColumns"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Now inside the `mat-cell` I dont' want to display the object properties but I want to include an `<input>` like follows :

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="column.cell(row)">
</mat-cell>
```

I want to have something like this but where the inputs are mapped with my objects.
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @JoeAllen: I used the classic html `table` `tr` and `td`